# memory leak when parsing data

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

I am trying to parse a an xml file. I am creating an array of dictionaries and then with these created arrays I am creating array with arrays. I am having memory leaks when I am copying my nsdictionary into array. can any one please help!!
Thanks

[image]

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

if(parseMode == 1){
    //        NSLog(@"found this start tag: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Group"]) {
        [tInState removeAllObjects];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"State_Name"]) {
        tData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        xmlItem = 0;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"T_Name"]) {
        xmlItem = 1;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"T_Address"]) {
        xmlItem = 2;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"T_Ph"]) {
        xmlItem = 3;
    }
}
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     

if (parseMode == 1) {
    //    NSLog(@"found this end tag: %@", elementName);
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"T_Info"]) {            
        [tInState addObject:[tData copy]];
        [tData autorelease];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Group"]) {
        [tlist addObject:tInState];

    }                      
}
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

if (parseMode == 0) {
    [self addToStateList:string];   
}
else  if (parseMode == 1) {
    //       NSLog(@"found this character: %@", string);
    switch (xmlItem) {
        case 0:               
            [tData setValue:string forKey:@"State_Name"];
            break;
        case 1:               
            [tData setValue:string forKey:@"T_Name"];
            break;
        case 2:               
            [tData setValue:string forKey:@"T_Address"];
            break;
        case 3:               
            [tData setValue:string forKey:@"T_Ph"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }        
}
```

}

Here tInState, tInState are nsmutablearray which I allocated in viewdidload function and released in releaseMemory. I went through the NScopy documents and it says when we use copy the ownership is transferred. I am releasing all my arrays so why is it still causing the problem??

Please help with this.
Thanks

Comment: I missed to clear the line in didendelement I am not releasing the nsdictionary(tdata). If I release its just crashing.

Comment: Please paste the code in and get rid of the screenshots (which are difficult to read)

Comment: Consider converting to ARC and these kind of issues disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 81 you are creating a copy of tData but not releasing it so it is leaking.  Instead of creating the copy in the `addObject` call, assign it to a variable, then pass it to `addObject`, then release it.

```
id temp = [tData copy];
[tInState addObject:temp];
[temp release];
```

Also, I'm assuming that the `[tData autorelease]` is actually meant to release the copy.  If so, that's not necessary.

Comment: @Jonathan - sure, but not much point in putting it in the autorelease pool if you know you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Yeah, but it's shorter, cleaner code and lets you skip creating a temporary. The overhead of `-autorelease` is extremely low--avoiding it tends to be premature optimization.

Comment: Thanks It worked. So is that when we make copy it should into any id??

Comment: You either have to assign the copy to a variable that you can call release on or, as @Jonathan pointed out, use the shorter, cleaner `[[tData copy] autorelease]` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your leak is because tData is doing what you told it, returning a copy. Calling autorelease on tData on the next line is autoreleasing the original tData and that will result in an over release. You will need to change that line to this `[tInState addObject:[[tData copy] autorelease]];` and remove the autorelease call on the next line.